# SpriteKit reference nodes from level editor

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using the scene editor in SpriteKit to place color sprites and assign them textures using the Attributes Inspector. My problem is trying to figure out how to reference those sprites from my GameScene file. For example, I'd like to know when a sprite is a certain distance from my main character.

**Edit - code added**

I'm adding the code because for some reason, appzYourLife's answer worked great in a simple test project, but not in my code. I was able to use Ron Myschuk's answer which I also included in the code below for reference. (Though, as I look at it now I think the array of tuples was overkill on my part.) As you can see, I have a Satellite class with some simple animations. There's a LevelManager class that replaces the nodes from the scene editor with the correct objects. And finally, everything gets added to the world node in GameScene.swift.

**Satellite Class**

```
func spawn(parentNode:SKNode, position: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)) {
        parentNode.addChild(self)
        createAnimations()
        self.size = size
        self.position = position
        self.name = "satellite"
        self.runAction(satAnimation)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: size.width / 2)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.satellite.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.laser.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    }

    func createAnimations() {
        let flyFrames:[SKTexture] = [textureAtlas.textureNamed("sat1.png"),
                                     textureAtlas.textureNamed("sat2.png")]
        let flyAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(flyFrames, timePerFrame: 0.14)
        satAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(flyAction)

        let warningFrames:[SKTexture] = [textureAtlas.textureNamed("sat8.png"),
                                         textureAtlas.textureNamed("sat1.png")]
        let warningAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(warningFrames, timePerFrame: 0.14)
        warningAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(warningAction)
    }

    func warning() {
        self.runAction(warningAnimation)
    }
```

**Level Manager Class**

```
import SpriteKit

class LevelManager
{
    let levelNames:[String] = ["Level1"]
    var levels:[SKNode] = []

    init()
    {
        for levelFileName in levelNames {
            let level = SKNode()
            if let levelScene = SKScene(fileNamed: levelFileName) {
                for node in levelScene.children {
                        switch node.name! {
                        case "satellite":
                            let satellite = Satellite()
                            satellite.spawn(level, position: node.position)
                        default: print("Name error: \(node.name)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            levels.append(level)
        }
    }

    func addLevelsToWorld(world: SKNode)
    {
        for index in 0...levels.count - 1 {
            levels[index].position = CGPoint(x: -2000, y: index * 1000)
            world.addChild(levels[index])
        }
    }
}
```

**GameScene.swift - didMoveToView**

```
world = SKNode()
world.name = "world"
addChild(world)

physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

levelManager.addLevelsToWorld(self.world)
levelManager.levels[0].position = CGPoint(x:0, y: 0)

//This does not find the satellite nodes
let satellites = children.flatMap { $0 as? Satellite }

//This does work
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*") {
   node, stop in
   if (node.name == "satellite") {
      self.satTuple.0 = node.position
      self.satTuple.1 = (node as? SKSpriteNode)!
      self.currentSatellite.append(self.satTuple)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to loop through the children of the scene and assign them to local objects to use in your code

assuming your objects in your SKS file were named  Obstacle1, Obstacle2, Obstacle3

Once in local objects you can check and do whatever you want with them

```
let obstacle1 = SKSpriteNode()
let obstacle2 = SKSpriteNode()
let obstacle3 = SKSpriteNode()
let obstacle3Location = CGPointZero


func setUpScene() {

    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*") {
        node, stop in

        if (node.name == "Obstacle1") {
            self.obstacle1 = node
        }
        else if (node.name == "Obstacle2") {
            self.obstacle2 = node
        }
        else if (node.name == "Obstacle3") {
            self.obstacle3Location = node.position
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### The Obstacle class

First of all you should create an `Obstacle` class like this.

```
class Obstacle: SKSpriteNode { }
```

Now into the scene editor associate the `Obstacle` class to your obstacles images

[image]

### The Player class

Do the same for Player, create a class

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode { }
```

and associate it to your player sprite.

### Checking for collisions

Now into GameScene.swift change the `updated` method like this

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    let obstacles = children.flatMap { $0 as? Obstacle }
    let player = childNodeWithName("player") as! Player

    let obstacleNearSprite = obstacles.contains { (obstacle) -> Bool in
        let distance = hypotf(Float(player.position.x) - Float(obstacle.position.x), Float(player.position.y) - Float(obstacle.position.y))
        return distance < 100
    }

    if obstacleNearSprite {
        print("Oh boy!")
    }

}
```

### What does it do?

The first line retrieves all your obstacles into the scene.
the second line retrieves the player (and does crash if it's not present).

Next it put into the `obstacleNearSprite` constant the true value if there is at least one Obstacle at no more then 100 points from `Player`.

And finally use the `obstacleNearSprite` to print something.

### Optimizations

The updated method gets called 60 times per second. We put these 2 lines into it

```
let obstacles = children.flatMap { $0 as? Obstacle }
let player = childNodeWithName("player") as! Player
```

in order to retrieves the sprites we need. With the modern hardware it is not a problem but you should save references to Obstacle and Player instead then searching for them in every frame.

Build a nice game ;)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I was able to get everything to work as you said when I created a test project. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work in my project. children.flatmap comes up empty. I have added the code to my question with the hope that it will help.